# playing multiple videos in flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging, video, size

I have a blank project that simply plays two video files. No matter what I try, the second video gets sized to the same as the first. Please tell me this isn't a Flash bug and that there's something I can do to accomplish this. Here's my document class:

```
package{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class Test extends MovieClip{

        public function Test(){

            var nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            var ns = new NetStream(nc);
            var vid1 = new Video(120, 88);
            vid1.x = 100;
            vid1.y = 300;
            this.addChild(vid1);

            vid1.attachNetStream(ns);
            ns.client = new Object();
            ns.play("video/testvideo1.flv");    


            var ns2 = new NetStream(nc);
            var vid2 = new Video(600,678);
            vid2.x = 500;
            vid2.y = 50;
            this.addChild(vid2);

            vid2.attachNetStream(ns2);
            ns2.client = new Object();
            ns2.play("video/testvideo2.flv");


        }
    }
}
```

If you trace out the size of vid2 immediately after you create it at (600,768), it says (120,88) - the size of the first video.

Comment: Congrats, you've found a bug! LOL

Comment: That's great. How am I supposed to execute this project which requires multiple video clips playing on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blogpost: http://synja.com/?p=14

Apparently you just have to specify the width and height after initialization. So:

```
var vid1 = new Video(120, 88);
vid1.width = 120;
vid1.height = 88;

[...]

var vid2 = new Video(600,678);
vid2.width = 600;
vid2.height = 678;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no special reason both videos have to play within the same SWF, you could just host both videos as separate SWFs in a single HTML page.  If you need some coordination between them, you can write a JavaScript bridge easily for this, using ExternalInterface.

Comment: Maybe even separated Movie Clips inside the Flash Movie may work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience playing videos of two different sizes. The tricks is creating a rectangle drawing and converting it to a movie clip. Assign an instance name for that movie clip. Then make a duplicate of that movie clip and assign a different instance name. Place your 2 movie clips on stage and resize the particular movie clip according to the size you needed using the resize tool. Target each movie clip's instance name to load your video on stage.